# Retrieving password expiry date and remaining days to expiry date

Tags: passwords, spring-ldap

I am trying to retrieve the max password age and a specific user's last password set date in order to calculate his/her remaining days to expiry.

But I am having issue getting the value of maxPwdAge and maxLastSet as context.getStringAttribute("pwdMaxAge") and context.getStringAttribute("pwdLastSet") return null while I could get back the user's name and display name.

Are the attributes "maxPwdAge" and "maxLastSet" the right ones to use for spring ldap?

```
@Override public LdapUser mapFromContext(Object ctx) {
  DirContextAdapter context = (DirContextAdapter) ctx;
  LdapUser ldapUser = new LdapUser();

  ldapUser.setName(context.getStringAttribute("name"));
  ldapUser.setGivenName(context.getStringAttribute("displayName"));
  ldapUser.setPwdAge(context.getStringAttribute("pwdMaxAge"));
  ldapUser.setPwdLastSet(context.getStringAttribute("pwdLastSet));

  return ldapUser;
}
```

Comment: If your LDAP Directory Server supports the behera Password Policy controls [https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-10], you could use this to let the DS tell you when a bind operation is performed.

Answer (score 0):

The maxPwdAge is stored inside the object class "domain" or "domainDns" in the base of the domain controller.

query().base(DC=test,DC=local).searchScope(SearchScope.OBJECT).where("objectclass").is("domain")